# https is ignoring some of my commits

Tags: php, http, authentication, https, version-control

I have a drupal site connected to another non-drupal site. (All php) They have Single sign-on. Some info is stored in a cookie. So when a user signs in in the Drupal site and clicks the link to the other site he is automatically signed in in the next site.  The new (or existing) user gets generated (or updated) automatically every time.

Now the problem:

Somehow some of my changes to a couple of pages regarding this authentication are ignored when I use the HTTPS:// link. It looks like it keeps checking the old files... Like they are stored in a hidden place? When I change to HTTP:// suddenly it takes the new modified files...

And it only happens to files about the authentication process. All my other commits to other parts of the second website work like normal. Just these couple of authentication files get ignored.

Does anybody knows why https behaves like this?

Could this be server caching or php caching ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post the answer to my own question so hopefully I can help someone else with a similar problem.

There were 2 files with the same name.
The HTTPS login file was in the private_html folder.
the http login file was in the public_html folder.

They both had the same name. So when I updated the http file and pushed it to the server, the https login file stayed untouched. And since the https login file was not in the git repository I couldn't find it locally, but only on the server...

Problem solved, so no caching problems at all.